# Modify attributes of a USB memory stick

Tags: python

Is there a python command to modify the attributes of the archives of a memory USB.That is similar to command  of the cmd window ( Attrib / s / d -s -h -r * . *). Use this does not work:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("F: Attrib /s /d -r -h -s *.*")
```

Comment: Please specify what doesn't work. Is there an error message? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

After encotre find the solution that was : create a .bat file and then call to subprocess call ( "").

```
import subprocess 
subprocess.call("eliminar.bat")
```

The .bat file would contain the following: first letter would point to the drive or the device, then the command as follows .

F:

Attrib / s / d -s -h -r * . *